# Connecting SQL Server to Oracle database using Polybase

Tags: sql-server, polybase

Trying to create an External Source using Polybase in SQL Server and got this error:

> > Msg 46505, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Missing required external DDL option 'type

However, base online examples there was no type when creating the external source.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE test_external_data_source_name with (
    LOCATION = 'oracle://10.170.35.249:1522',
    credential = credential_name
);
```

Comment: Hey there! Can you expand your question a bit, making it easier to understand?

Comment: Can you post the exact error please? Looking at the reference, there definitely is a `type` parameter. I guess it should be `RDBMS` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-data-source-transact-sql?view=sqlallproducts-allversions

Comment: This is the error message: Msg 46505, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Missing required external DDL option 'type'.

Comment: Is PolyBase enabled? See blog post: https://nielsberglund.com/2019/12/30/more-polybase-issues-in-sql-server-2019-developers-edition/